# Using Java3D with SBT

Tags: java, maven, java-native-interface, sbt, java-3d

I have successfully used Java3D by copying JAR files and native binaries to the appropriate paths on a fresh machine. However, I'd like to replicate that using SBT.

Is there a way to configure SBT so that Java3D just *works* out of the box with only the Maven dependency specified?

#### Update: current configuration

In my `build.sbt` I have the following specified:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "java3d" % "j3d-core-utils" % "1.3.1",
  "java3d" % "j3d-core" % "1.3.1",
  "java3d" % "vecmath" % "1.3.1"
)
```

These are from [MVNRepository.com](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/java3d).

Comment: Do you know where a Maven repository is with the Java3D files?

Comment: Yes. Added the relevant lines from my current `build.sbt`.

Comment: I can see that there's Java 3D 1.5.1 at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-java-client-419417.html#java3d-1.5.1-oth-JPR. You should have more success on https://java3d.dev.java.net/ that appears the home of the project right now.